# I am looking for a live snip tool

Tags: python, chrome, screen-recording, screenshot

I am imagining a program like the Windows Snipping Tool but instead of making a jpeg, it creates a 'window' with a live view of just the highlighted area of that application's window. Sidebar: it would be good if this could be made 'always on top' as well.

Imagining a use case: Live Snip out a YouTube video and then go to another go to another tab and do work while watching the YouTube video. (I know there are Chrome extensions that can do a pop out for YouTube, but I would like to do this with other things as well)

If there is no software currently, is this programmable (hopefully in Python, because that's what I know best)?

Comment: I see this javascript code: 
`window.open(location.href, "detab", "toolbar=0", "width=500, height=500");`
This is nice but not exactly what I would want. This would be close enough if I could get it to only pop out a certain part of the html and not the whole page.

Comment: If you use `window.open(location.href, "detab", "toolbar=0", "width=500, height=500");` on a YouTube URL like: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/X where X = the YouTube URL after the '='` Example: https://www.youtube.com/embed/r9tbusKyvMY

The above gets is basically what I want, but is only applicable to YouTube videos. I would like to be able to do this exact same idea with other chunks of html and, if possible, other programs as well.

Comment: I supposed this would be like a live screencast of a section of a program but on your own pc instead of screencasting to another person's PC.